# How to zoom for an iOS drawing app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I'm making a drawing application for the iPad where users use one finger to draw lines and rectangles. However, i'm struggling with adding the zoom features.

Some background info of my current code:

- There is an appdelegate which sets the view controller
- Most of the action takes place inside the view controller including IBActions, popovers, etc.
- The xib file uses a custom view i made and this is where all the drawing actions take place

This is what i've done so far:
Inside viewDidLoad, i have

```
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(768, 1024)]; 
    [scrollView setMinimumZoomScale:0.5];
    [scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:5];
    [scrollView setDelegate:self];
```

In my xib file, i tried tossing a UIScrollView ontop of my customview (and making the IB connections), but of course, it covers my custom view and you can't draw. I tried the reverse by placing a UIScrollView followed by my own custom view, but i still can't draw either.

Any pointers on what to do?

Comment: Can you share your final solution? How did you finally end up implementing zoom in your drawing app? I'm looking for an efficient solution myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181707/drawing-on-a-zoomable-view

Comment: Well, my internship ended before i could finish it

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your viewController in the .h file:

```
<UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

An then this on your .m file:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return backgroundImage;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidEndZooming");
}
```

Also, make sure that in your xib, the scrollview's delegate is linked to File's Owner.

Edit 1: [image: The Toolbar is Above the UIScrollView]

Comment: Hi, i'm trying out your suggestion. I already have the UIScrollViewDelegate in my .h file and inside IB, i have the scrollview delegate set to the file's owner. However, two problems remain: i can't draw lines or shapes and when i zoom out, the bottom toolbar zooms out as well. How can i rectify these?

Comment: Is your toolbar inside the ScrollView?

Comment: I have my toolbar on top of my custom view. Then i tossed a UIScrollVIew over. This makes better sense now, so i assume i remove the tool bar, place the UIScroll view, and then add my toolbar? Is there an easier way to move the toolbar up a layer? I will try this out. Thanks

Comment: What do you been by "tossed a UIScrollViewOver"? Your toolbar should be above "in a view perspective" and in an " NIB hierarchical perspective". What i mean is, I should be able to see the UIScrollView and the ToolBar, and play around with the scrollview without interfering with the ToolBar. Check my edit.