# Drawing on a zoomable view

Tags: ios, uiview, drawing

I'm working on a small drawing application, which has a basic requirement of supporting zoom-in/out. I have two main issues:

1. Drawing doesn't appear crisp and clear, when view is zoomed/transformed. Is there a better approach, or is there a way to improve the drawing when the view is zoomed?
2. The drawing performance is slow, when drawing on 1200 x 1200 pts canvas (on iPhone). Any chance I can improve it for large canvas sizes?

**Zooming Code:**

```
- (void)scale:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    [self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    UIView *canvas = [gestureRecognizer view];

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
        [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        // Calculate the drawing view's size
        CGSize drawingViewSize = ...;

        // Calculate the minimum allowed tranform size
        // Developer's Note: I actually wanted to use the size 1/4th of the view
        // but self.view.frame.size doesn't return the correct (actual) width and height
        // It returns these values inverted i.e. width as height, and vice verse.
        // The reason is that the view appears to be transformed (90 degrees).
        // Since there's no work-around this, so for now, I'm just using fixed values.
        CGSize minTranformSize = CGSizeMake(100.0f, 100.0f);

        if ((minTranformSize.width > drawingViewSize.width) && (minTranformSize.height > drawingViewSize.height)) {
            minTranformSize = drawingViewSize;
        }

        // Transform the view, provided
        // 1. It won't scale more than the original size of the background image
        // 2. It won't scale less than the minimum possible transform
        CGSize transformedSize = CGSizeMake(canvas.frame.size.width * [gestureRecognizer scale],
                                            canvas.frame.size.height * [gestureRecognizer scale]);

        if ((transformedSize.width <= drawingViewSize.width) && (transformedSize.height <= drawingViewSize.height) &&
            (transformedSize.width >= minTranformSize.width) && (transformedSize.height >= minTranformSize.height)) {

            canvas.transform = CGAffineTransformScale([canvas transform],
                                                      [gestureRecognizer scale],
                                                      [gestureRecognizer scale]);
        }

        [gestureRecognizer setScale:1.0];

    } else if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        // Recenter the container view, if required (piece is smaller than the view and it's not aligned)
        CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;

        if ((canvas.frame.size.width < viewSize.width) ||
            (canvas.frame.size.height < viewSize.height)) {

            canvas.center = CGPointMake(viewSize.width/2, viewSize.height/2);
        }

        // Adjust the x/y coordinates, if required (piece is larger than the view and it's moving outwards from the view)
        if (((canvas.frame.origin.x > 0) || (canvas.frame.origin.y > 0)) &&
            ((canvas.frame.size.width >= viewSize.width) && (canvas.frame.size.height >= viewSize.height))) {

            canvas.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                      0.0,
                                      canvas.frame.size.width,
                                      canvas.frame.size.height);
        }

        canvas.frame = CGRectIntegral(canvas.frame);
    }
}
```

**Drawing Code**

```
- (void)draw {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    if (self.fillColor) {
        [self.fillColor setFill];
        [self.path fill];
    }

    if ([self.strokeColor isEqual:[UIColor clearColor]]) {
        [self.path strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeClear alpha:1.0];

    } else if (self.strokeColor) {
        [self.strokeColor setStroke];
        [self.path stroke];
    }

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a pretty complicated problem, that I have struggled a lot with.

I ended up converting the drawings to vector.

1. draw all lines in one layer, draw all fills in another.
2. Convert the line drawings to Vector, using potrace (http://potrace.sourceforge.net/)
3. draw the vector using SVGKit
   (https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) and hide the layer drawn in 1)

It is working pretty well and fairly fast, but it requires a lot of work. We have an app in our company that applies this technique:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ideal-paint-hd-mormor/id569450492?mt=8.

If your only problem is performance, try taking a look at `CATiledLayer`. (also used in app mentioned above). It will increase performance tremendously (You can find a pretty good tutorial here http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/01/subduing-catiledlayer/).

Good luck! :)

Comment: Indeed, it looks like a lot of work, and I wonder what kind of performance (in terms of both time and fps) you're getting in your paint application?

Comment: The tracing is pretty time consuming (several seconds), drawing is on the other hand very fast. Our strategy is to let the user draw without tracing, until the user chooses another tool og start zooming. Then we show a spinner while we perform the tracing.

Answer (score -1):

First of all You are Transforming View this is not better way for zooming .Transforming may use only for increase or decrease size of UIVew For zooming you can d this.

1) get get pic of screen by using this code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.drawingView.bounds.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
//[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
[self.layerContainerView.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[scaleLabel setHidden:FALSE];
return screenShot;
```

2) then put it on some UIImageView and then perform Zomming on this Image

```
 scrollView.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.000;
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 30.0f;
[self centerScrollViewContents];
CGFloat newZoomScale = self.scrollView.zoomScale / 1.5f;
newZoomScale = MAX(newZoomScale, self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale);
[self.scrollView setZoomScale:newZoomScale animated:YES];
```

3) then again Set zoomed image on uiView's background

this works perfect for me hope this will also works for you

Comment: This approach will zoom on the image using a technique similar to the one OP is already using. You will NOT get crisp and clear images by simply zooming/scale-transforming an image.